# Convert JSON string in html into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I've retrieved some data in JSON format from MarkitOnDemand API, the JSON content I want is inside the body tag of the html string like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Autocompelete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
{"Status":"SUCCESS","Name":"Apple Inc","Symbol":"AAPL","LastPrice":109.59,"Change":1.91,"ChangePercent":1.77377414561664,"Timestamp":"Wed Mar 30 15:59:00 UTC-04:00 2016","MSDate":42459.6659722222,"MarketCap":607630850970,"Volume":3211276,"ChangeYTD":105.26,"ChangePercentYTD":4.11362340870226,"High":110.41,"Low":108.6,"Open":108.64}</body>
</html>
```

The above code of html string is in the "data" string of my AJAX call below:

```
$(function(){
    $('#searchform').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var requestdata = 'symbol=' + $('#query').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "receivesearch.php",
            method: "get",
            data: requestdata,
            success: function(data){  //html string in this data parameter

                //CONFUSED HERE

            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I failed to get the JSON string out of the body tag and parse it into JSON object...

Could anyone please help me with this problem? Thank you so much!!

Here is my php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Autocompelete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['symbol'])){
        $lookupURL = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=" . $_GET['symbol'];
        $jsonhtml = file_get_contents($lookupURL);
        echo $jsonhtml;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would you send it that way and not as `application/json` output? Seems like a silly way to send json and also include extra scripts with it also

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: var obj = $.parseJSON( $('body').html())

Comment: Have you tried adding `headers: {          
     Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"   
} ` to your ajax request?

Comment: Http Get methods cannot contain a payload so you cant use the `data` param in your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: The reason your PHP is returning HTML is because you have nested your PHP in an HTML document.  All you need is the bit between the PHP tags `<?php //THIS STUFF ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Markit On Demand API supports JSON, so there's something wrong with your original query.

Have a look at this URL for an example: 
 http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL

It returns pure JSON data, which can be processed using `$.parseJSON(data)`

**UPDATE: Try this code for example:**

```js
var requestData = 'symbol=AAPL';
$.ajax({
    url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json",
    method: "get",
    data: requestdata,
    success: function(data){  //html string in this data parameter
        $symbolResponse = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2: Use this PHP Code:**  (Just this code and nothing else)

```php
<?php

if (isset($_GET['symbol'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $lookupURL = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=" . $_GET['symbol'];
    $jsonhtml = file_get_contents($lookupURL);
    echo $jsonhtml;
}

?>
```

Comment: So I tried to use dataType: "json" in my $.ajax(), but it couldn't retrieve the result of the JSON data. I used following code to call the api:   if(isset($_GET['symbol'])){
        $lookupURL = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=" . $_GET['symbol'];
        $jsonhtml = file_get_contents($lookupURL);
        echo $jsonhtml;
    }

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work! But I just wonder why my original code using php as a proxy doesn't work, could you please give me some hint?

Comment: @Paul Have you tried getting your PHP proxy to call the URL as listed here: http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json ? Maybe post your PHP code in the original question.

Comment: Thank you again, Tim! My php code was added above in the original question now. @Tim Ogilvy

Comment: @Paul see my updated answer. Remove the html from your PHP file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! The problem solved... I shouldn't add the html part in the first place...

Comment: @Paul my pleasure, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the result twice: once as HTML using `$.parseHTML()`, then you can get the text from that and pass this into `$.parseJSON()`.

Something along these lines:

```
success: function(data){  //html string in this data parameter
    var html = $.parseHTML(data);
    var body = $(html).text();
    var json = $.parseJSON(body);
    // use the JSON data here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried something similar with your code, however there is a mistake "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 5 column 3 of the JSON data", not sure why this happens.

Comment: Well, the info with the PHP proxy would have been essential. My code would work fine if the body text was pure JSON data (which it was not because your proxy did not HTML-encode the result, so that any `<` or `&` in the JSON would render the HTML invalid).

Answer (score -1):

You have the option of `JSON.parse(data)`, `$.parseJSON(data)`, or the un-advised `eval(data)`.